# Excel sheet cell dispalying Date and time using c#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am importing Excel sheet into DataGridView.I have one of the cell has date as 05-06-2017.But while dispalyig under DataGridView it is showing 05-06-2017 AM 12:00:00.

Can you please help me how can i display only Date.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to format the DateTime object [DateTime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

```
d.Format("d")
```

Alternatively, set the format on the gridview column itself using the DefaultCellStyle.Format property with a parameter of "d"

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! i used this cell format : like   objPreview.dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"; But it is showing with date and  time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a format issue. If your binding then use a string format of "MM-dd-yyyy" (assuming USA date formatting). Do a google for ".net custom date format". I think you will find that the XAML binding has a 'StringFormat' (or similar) option.

Best of luck

Rob